# How to implement or use LRU cache if already present in Java

Tags: java, caching

I want a LRU cache that contains `<String, FileName>` with some basic features

- when it removed Least recently used entry, it should closed file.
- Cache should be able to handle multiple thread request.

I know that, we can use **LinkedHashMap** as a LRU cache by overriding **removeEldestEntry** method. But i want to close the file once it will be removed during new entry. It there any way we can achieved this?

Comment: You know that the argument to `removeEldestEntry` is the entry to be removed if you return true?

Comment: Maybe take a look at Guava's caching: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained